# Reaction between Ammonium chloride, Concentrated sulphuric acid and copper turnings

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, salt

During a salt test, dry test for acid radical , mixed ammonium chloride with concentrated sulphuric acid and heated the mixture and added copper turnings to the mixture, the mixture on heating turned yellow.

Sulphur Dioxide was also evolved as detected by its odour.

Bubbling across the copper turnings were observed.

Wanted to know the chemistry behind the reaction, composition of the yellow compound.

Comment: Be aware that laconic, not elaborated questions without hints of solving attempt are usually frown upon and they get often closed.  OTOH, well elaborated questions have higher probability to  receive acceptable answers.  [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Mixing ammonia, metals, and acids has been known to produce explosive things like nitrides, fulminates, and ammonium nitrate.  Great care should be taken. Potential side reactions should be thoroughly researched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible process expressed in ionic and summary formula forms:

\begin{align}
\ce{4 Cl- + 2 H+ + H2SO4 + Cu &-> CuCl4^2- + SO2 + 2 H2O}\\
\ce{4 NH4Cl + 3 H2SO4 + Cu &-> (NH4)2[CuCl4] + SO2 + 2 NH4HSO4 + 2 H2O }
\end{align}

As oxidative behavior of hot concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$ is well known:

$$\ce{Cu + 5 H2SO4(l) -> Cu^2+(solv) + SO2(g) + 2 H3O+(solv) + 4 HSO4-(solv)}$$

Comment: Check out oxyhemocyanin nitrogen-copper-oxygen chemistry!

Answer (score 1):

Poutnik's explanation is consistent with experimental observations and yellow color of chloro copper complex. This is a known complex of copper. The alternative proposed hypothesis in another answer suggesting the formation of $\ce{NOCl}$ or $\ce{NO}$ is not correct because it contradicts a well known analytical reaction employed in Kjeldahl method. Here nitrogen containing compounds (say meat, food) are digested with concentrated sulfuric acid at very high temperature, near the boiling point, and the end product is ammonium sulfate! So it is known that sulfuric acid will not oxidize ammonium ion to nitrogen oxide or other complexes even under extreme conditions.

Comment: [Kjeldahl method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kjeldahl_method) "yields lower protein results when CuSO4 used as a catalyst".  Why?

Comment: An interesting reference [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0926337315300369).  It even has pictures.

Comment: I do not trust Wikipedia for scientific purposes and their claim is also incorrect. Wikipedia is a excellent starting place to search not the end. The second reference has nothing to do with sulfuric acid. A senior good old scientist told me to read at least 12 papers before forming an opinion. One can start from a very reliable reference, Determination of Kjeldahl Nitrogen in Fertilizers by AOAC Official Method: Effect of Copper Sulfate as a Catalyst. They say there is no difference!

Comment: I ran Kjeldahls years ago.  I appreciate your point of view.  I will continue to research this.  Good old evolution disposes of ammonia by forming urea.

Comment: [Some](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5960693/) bacteria can oxidize ammonia with a "red copper protein" enzyme. (page 2).

Answer (score 0):

It might be [nitrosyl chloride](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrosyl_chloride).  At elevated temperatures ammonia can be oxidized to  [NO](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_oxide), which can oxidize to [NO2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_dioxide), and further to [nitric acid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_acid).

In acidic solution, chlorine can combine with NO to form NOCl, a yellow gas.

Since essentially a mixture of aqua Regia results, ammonia and copper may both be subsequently oxidized.

It is certainly hoped this was run in a well ventilated hood.

Comment: There is also another possible reaction as mentioned in Poutniks answer between copper and H2SO4 --> Copper sulphate and SO2 gas.

Comment: Ammonia cannot be oxidized to NO in solution even by sulfuric. This speculation is incorrect.  The elevated temperature is around 1000 degrees.

Comment: @Achem I remind you that equilibration chemistry only requires that product can be produced and more will be if it is removed as NOCl.  Note that Poutnik explanation is not favored either, but can occur in sufficient quantities to be significant. (Unless you have a better explanation).  Further more formation of NO can be catalyzed at lower temperatures.  NOCl is known to occur in aqua regia.

Comment: Further related [reading](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jacs.2c07977)